# Scroll bar gets reset in dijit Calendar week view and day view

Tags: dojo

I have a calendar which have month view,week view and day view. When i try to scroll in week or day view, the scroll resets to the top. This happens when I scroll by dragging the scroll bar using mouse. But when i scroll using the scroll in mouse, this issue does not occur. Please provide your inputs on why this occurs.These views are inside portlet. This issue occurs inside portlet only. Outside portlet, this is not happening.

I have the code in JSFiddle- jsfiddle.net/libinjose/N4YCw/5. I have edited CalendarBase.js,PortletDialogSettings.js-   jsfiddle.net/libinjose/VkQUH. Added new DayCalendar.js which uses DayCalendar.html. Similarly for week and month view. These can be found in the second JSFiddle.

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's no way to tell. Please post your code, preferably in a JSFiddle.

Comment: I have the code in JSFiddle-jsfiddle.net/libinjose/N4YCw/5. I have edited CalendarBase.js,PortletDialogSettings.js-jsfiddle.net/libinjose/VkQUH. Added new DayCalendar.js which uses DayCalendar.html. Similarly for week and month view. These can be found in the second JSFiddle.